# NullPointerException when trying to Filter JTable

Tags: java, jtable

I have an exception when setting a row sorter to table. I checked it by println it's actually null, but I can't see clearly why. Here is my main class and abstract table model implementation class.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.SpinnerDateModel;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
public class Framer{
    final static JTextPane              money   =new     JTextPane();
    static String                           moneyS  ="0";
    // static DialogWin dialog;
    static Filer                        filer;
    public static JTextField            name;
    private static JTextField           surname;
    private static JTextField           cost;
    static JTextPane                    clientsNum;
    static String                       forward;
    public static JTable                table_1;
    static SModel                       dmodel;
    private static JTextField           search;
    static TableRowSorter<TableModel>   sorter;
    public static void filter(){
        table_1.setRowSorter(sorter);
        final String text=search.getText();
        if(text.length()==0){
            sorter.setRowFilter(null);
        }else{
            try{
                sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter    (text));
            }catch(final PatternSyntaxException pse){
                System.err.println("Bad regex pattern");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void load() throws Exception{
        if(!filer.empty){
            dmodel.vv=filer.FilerRead().vv;
            dmodel.fireTableDataChanged();
        }
    }
    public static void main(final String args[]) throws Exception{
        // for(int i=0;i<headings.length;i++){
        // data[i][i]="#";
        // }
        filer=new Filer();
        final JFrame jFrame=new JFrame("Кассовый Журнал");
        jFrame.setSize(769,708);
        /*
         * final UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] info=UIManager
         * .getInstalledLookAndFeels(); for(final LookAndFeelInfo     element:info){
         * System.out.print(element); } try{
         * UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info[info.length-4].getClassName    ());
         * }catch(final ClassNotFoundException e){ // TODO Auto-    generated catch
         * block e.printStackTrace(); }catch(final     InstantiationException e){ //
         * TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }    catch(final
         * IllegalAccessException e){ // TODO Auto-generated catch     block
         * e.printStackTrace(); }catch(final     UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e){
     * // TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }
     */
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final JMenuBar menuBar=new JMenuBar();
    jFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    final JTextPane textPane_2=new JTextPane();
    textPane_2.setEditable(false);
    textPane_2.setText("Всего за период:");
    menuBar.add(textPane_2);
    clientsNum=new JTextPane();
    clientsNum.setEditable(false);
    menuBar.add(clientsNum);
    final JTextPane textPane_3=new JTextPane();
    textPane_3.setEditable(false);
    textPane_3.setText("Доходы");
    menuBar.add(textPane_3);
    menuBar.add(money);
    search=new JTextField();
    search.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void focusGained(final FocusEvent arg0){
            search.setText("");
        }
    });
    final JButton button_3=new JButton("Найти");
    button_3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent arg0){
            filter();
        }
    });
    menuBar.add(button_3);
    search.setBackground(new Color(255,255,0));
    search.setText("Поиск");
    menuBar.add(search);
    search.setColumns(10);
    jFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
    dmodel=new SModel();
    final JDesktopPane desktopPane=new JDesktopPane();
    jFrame.getContentPane().add(desktopPane);
    final SpringLayout springLayout=new SpringLayout();
    desktopPane.setLayout(springLayout);
    final JInternalFrame DateFrame=new JInternalFrame("Фильтрация по дате");
    DateFrame.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,DateFrame,0,
            SpringLayout.NORTH,desktopPane);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,DateFrame,0,
            SpringLayout.WEST,desktopPane);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,DateFrame,229,
            SpringLayout.WEST,desktopPane);
    desktopPane.add(DateFrame);
    final JInternalFrame TableFrame=new JInternalFrame("Список приемов");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,TableFrame,0,
            SpringLayout.NORTH,DateFrame);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,TableFrame,0,
            SpringLayout.EAST,DateFrame);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,TableFrame,0,
            SpringLayout.EAST,desktopPane);
    TableFrame.setVisible(true);
    desktopPane.add(TableFrame);
    final JInternalFrame AddFrame=new JInternalFrame("Создать новую запись");
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH,TableFrame,-10,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,AddFrame);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH,DateFrame,-1,
            SpringLayout.NORTH,AddFrame);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,AddFrame,0,
            SpringLayout.WEST,desktopPane);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,AddFrame,0,
            SpringLayout.EAST,DateFrame);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,AddFrame,177,
            SpringLayout.NORTH,desktopPane);
    springLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH,AddFrame,0,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,desktopPane);
    TableFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,0));
    final JScrollPane scrollPane=new JScrollPane();
    TableFrame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    load();
    refresh();
    final JTable table_1=new JTable(dmodel);
    table_1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table_1);
    final SpringLayout springLayout_1=new SpringLayout();
    DateFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(springLayout_1);
    final JLabel label=new JLabel("С:");
    DateFrame.getContentPane().add(label);
    final JSpinner from=new JSpinner();
    from.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),
            new Date(1325358000000L),null,Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH));
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,from,10,
            SpringLayout.NORTH,DateFrame.getContentPane());
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,from,29,
            SpringLayout.WEST,DateFrame.getContentPane());
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,from,-10,
            SpringLayout.EAST,DateFrame.getContentPane());
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,label,6,
            SpringLayout.NORTH,from);
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,label,-6,
            SpringLayout.WEST,from);
    DateFrame.getContentPane().add(from);
    final JLabel label_1=new JLabel("По:");
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,label_1,34,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,label);
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,label_1,0,
            SpringLayout.EAST,label);
    DateFrame.getContentPane().add(label_1);
    final JSpinner till=new JSpinner();
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,till,22,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,from);
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,till,0,
            SpringLayout.WEST,from);
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,till,-10,
            SpringLayout.EAST,DateFrame.getContentPane());
    till.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),
            new Date(1325358000000L),null,Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH));
    DateFrame.getContentPane().add(till);
    final JButton breport=new JButton("Отчет");
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,breport,23,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,till);
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,breport,0,
            SpringLayout.EAST,from);
    DateFrame.getContentPane().add(breport);
    final JButton button=new JButton("Загрузить");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent arg0){
            try{
                load();
            }catch(final Exception e){
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,button,23,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,till);
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,breport,6,
            SpringLayout.EAST,button);
    springLayout_1.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,button,0,
            SpringLayout.WEST,label_1);
    DateFrame.getContentPane().add(button);
    desktopPane.add(AddFrame);
    final SpringLayout springLayout_2=new SpringLayout();
    AddFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(springLayout_2);
    final JLabel label_2=new JLabel("Имя");
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(label_2);
    final JLabel label_3=new JLabel("Фамилия");
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,label_2,0,
            SpringLayout.WEST,label_3);
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH,label_2,-6,
            SpringLayout.NORTH,label_3);
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(label_3);
    name=new JTextField();
    name.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void focusGained(final FocusEvent arg0){
            name.setText("");
        }
    });
    name.setText("Введите значение");
    name.setToolTipText("");
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,name,65,
            SpringLayout.WEST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,name,-10,
            SpringLayout.EAST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,name,0,
            SpringLayout.NORTH,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(name);
    name.setColumns(10);
    surname=new JTextField();
    surname.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void focusGained(final FocusEvent arg0){
            surname.setText("");
        }
    });
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,label_3,3,
            SpringLayout.NORTH,surname);
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,surname,65,
            SpringLayout.WEST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,surname,-10,
            SpringLayout.EAST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    surname.setText("Введите значение");
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,surname,4,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,name);
    surname.setColumns(10);
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(surname);
    final JSpinner date=new JSpinner();
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,date,6,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,surname);
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,date,-10,
            SpringLayout.EAST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    date.setModel(new SpinnerDateModel(Calendar.getInstance().getTime(),
            new Date(1325358000000L),null,Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(date);
    cost=new JTextField();
    cost.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void focusGained(final FocusEvent arg0){
            cost.setText("");
        }
    });
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,cost,65,
            SpringLayout.WEST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    cost.setText("Введите значение");
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,cost,6,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,date);
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,cost,-10,
            SpringLayout.EAST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(cost);
    cost.setColumns(10);
    final JCheckBox forward_1=new JCheckBox("Предоплата");
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,forward_1,-20,
            SpringLayout.EAST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(forward_1);
    final JLabel label_4=new JLabel("Дата");
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,label_3,0,
            SpringLayout.WEST,label_4);
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,date,39,
            SpringLayout.EAST,label_4);
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,label_4,3,
            SpringLayout.NORTH,date);
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(label_4);
    final JLabel label_6=new JLabel("Доктор");
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,label_4,0,
            SpringLayout.WEST,label_6);
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,label_6,0,
            SpringLayout.WEST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(label_6);
    final JLabel label_5=new JLabel("Стоимость");
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,label_5,3,
            SpringLayout.NORTH,cost);
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,label_5,0,
            SpringLayout.WEST,label_6);
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(label_5);
    final JButton badd=new JButton("Добавить");
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,badd,-126,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,badd,10,
            SpringLayout.WEST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH,badd,-103,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,badd,-10,
            SpringLayout.EAST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(badd);
    final JButton bclear=new JButton("Очистить всю историю!");
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,bclear,-39,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,bclear,10,
            SpringLayout.WEST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH,bclear,-16,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,bclear,-10,
            SpringLayout.EAST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    sorter=new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(dmodel);
    bclear.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent arg0){
            dmodel.revomeAll();
            dmodel.fireTableDataChanged();
            try{
                refresh();
            }catch(final Exception e){
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{
                // table_1.setModel(filer.FilerRead());
            }catch(final Exception e1){
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(bclear);
    final JComboBox doctor=new JComboBox();
    doctor.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void focusGained(final FocusEvent arg0){
            doctor.setSelectedItem("");
        }
    });
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,label_6,3,
            SpringLayout.NORTH,doctor);
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,doctor,6,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,cost);
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,forward_1,14,
            SpringLayout.SOUTH,doctor);
    doctor.setEditable(true);
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,doctor,0,
            SpringLayout.EAST,name);
    doctor.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[]{"Введите текст"}));
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,doctor,0,
            SpringLayout.WEST,name);
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(doctor);
    final JButton button_1=new JButton("Распечатать");
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,button_1,10,
            SpringLayout.WEST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,button_1,-10,
            SpringLayout.EAST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(button_1);
    final JButton button_2=new JButton("Удалить прием");
    button_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent arg0){
            dmodel.removeSelected(table_1.getSelectedRow());
            try{
                refresh();
            }catch(final Exception e){
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dmodel.fireTableDataChanged();
        }
    });
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH,button_1,-6,
            SpringLayout.NORTH,button_2);
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST,button_2,0,
            SpringLayout.EAST,name);
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,button_2,10,
            SpringLayout.WEST,AddFrame.getContentPane());
    springLayout_2.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH,button_2,-6,
            SpringLayout.NORTH,bclear);
    AddFrame.getContentPane().add(button_2);
    badd.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent arg0){
            final Object[] o=new Object[6];
            o[0]=name.getText();
            o[1]=surname.getText();
            o[2]=date.getValue().toString();
            o[3]=cost.getText();
            o[4]=doctor.getSelectedItem();
            if(forward_1.isSelected()){
                o[5]="Да";
            }else{
                o[5]="Нет";
            }
            dmodel.addRow(o);
            table_1.setModel(dmodel);
            try{
                refresh();
            }catch(final Exception e){
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    AddFrame.setVisible(true);
    DateFrame.setVisible(true);
    // dialog.getdata(table);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
}
public static void refresh() throws Exception{
    filer.FilerWrite(dmodel);
    // dmodel=filer.FilerRead();
    dmodel.fireTableDataChanged();
    final StringBuffer s=new StringBuffer();
    final int i=dmodel.getRowCount();
    s.append(i);
    clientsNum.setText(s.toString());
    int mm=0;
    try{
        for(int j=0;j<dmodel.getRowCount();j++){
            final Integer m=new Integer((String)dmodel.vv.elementAt(j)
                    .elementAt(3));
            mm+=m.intValue();
        }
        s.delete(0,s.capacity());
        s.append(mm);
        money.setText(s.toString());
    }catch(final Exception e){}
}
}
```

Here is AbstractTableModel implementation

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
public class SModel extends AbstractTableModel implements Serializable{
    final static String[]   headings    =new String[]    {"Имя","Фамилия",
        "Дата приема","Стоимость приема     (тыс.сум.)","Врач","Предоплата"};
// final UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] info =UIManager
// .getInstalledLookAndFeels();
Vector                  v;
Vector<Vector<Object>>  vv          =new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
public void addRow(final Object[] o){
    v=new Vector<Object>();
    for(final Object element:o){
        v.add(element);
    }
    vv.add(v);
    fireTableDataChanged();
}
@Override
public int getColumnCount(){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return headings.length;
}
@Override
public String getColumnName(final int column){
    return headings[column];
}
@Override
public int getRowCount(){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return vv.size();
}
@Override
public Object getValueAt(final int arg0,final int arg1){
    return vv.get(arg0).get(arg1);
}
public void removeSelected(final int i){
    vv.removeElementAt(i);
}
public void revomeAll(){
    vv.removeAllElements();
}
}
```

And if needed Filer class for writing data or exactly model of table and reading it again

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
public class Filer{
File                dat;
DataOutputStream    doutput;
DataInputStream     dinput;
BufferedWriter      bwriter;
ObjectOutputStream  objout;
FileOutputStream    writer;
FileInputStream     reader;
ObjectInputStream   objin;
public boolean      empty   =true;
public Filer() throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException{
    dat=new File(".//data//data.dat");
    if(!dat.exists()){
        // System.out.println("here"+dat.getAbsolutePath());
        dat.createNewFile();
        empty=true;
    }else{
        empty=false;
    }
}
public SModel FilerRead() throws Exception{
    reader=new FileInputStream(dat);
    objin=new ObjectInputStream(reader);
    final SModel n=(SModel)objin.readObject();
    objin.close();
    return n;
}
public void FilerWrite(final SModel s) throws IOException{
    writer=new FileOutputStream(dat,false);
    objout=new ObjectOutputStream(writer);
    objout.writeObject(s);
    objout.close();
}
   }
```

It could be very cool, if would also help with data sort, which user will define through jspinners in top left internal frame. Thank you in advance!

Ok. I'm sorry. Here is the log:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Framer.filter(Framer.java:46)
at Framer$2.actionPerformed(Framer.java:109)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Problem appears when I entering a text to text field and trying to sort table by clicking button. Here is that stroke:

```
public static void filter(){
    table_1.setRowSorter(sorter);//It is here. table_1 equals null but I can't see why.
    final String text=search.getText();
    if(text.length()==0){
        sorter.setRowFilter(null);
    }else{
        try{
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
        }catch(final PatternSyntaxException pse){
            System.err.println("Bad regex pattern");
        }
    }
}
```

Oh, thanks I see now. I just rediclared it in main.

Comment: You should include the stack trace and indicate which line of code is causing the issue.

Comment: wanna tell us where the error is, or did you want us to actually read all of that?

Comment: It's not surprising that you can't see where the error is when you've written a wall of code like that. I sense an assembly programmer (especially judging by those aligned variables) ;)